# "U+2010" != "-" (or: handling copy/pasted unicode characters with Rails and Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unicode

I have a Rails 3.2 / Ruby 2.0 application backed with postgresql 9.3.

People copy/paste strings like "PS‐3002S‐BK" into a web form. The hyphens are "U+2010". The data is saved to postgresql as utf-8.

Then, when they search for "PS-3002S-BK" (with ascii hyphens), no data is returned because "PS‐3002S‐BK" != "PS-3002S-BK".

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

If you save your data to a column with well defined correct format (for example serial number or model number etc.) then always convert common kinds of [hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) (U+2010, U+2011) or [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) (U+2012, U+2013, U+2014, U+2015) to ASCII minus by your web application before saving it in a database. Preferably disallow anything but ASCII in this type of column.

Also when you search in this well defined format column then always convert hyphens and dashes to ASCII minus too.

If it's not possible because you are searching for example in ordinary text like comments etc., then you should split your search string "PS-3002S-BK" to words and search for "PS"+"3002S"+"BK".

Comment: So, basically just write the rules for replacing unicode hyphens with the ascii hyphen?

Comment: @JoeVanDyk Yes, and add a `CHECK` constraint in the database that rejects data that isn't the exact pattern you expect, with ascii hyphens. Have your application check the same thing earlier, and give the user an informative error message if it can't figure out how to fix the input.

Comment: ... and while you can search with `LIKE 'PS_3002S_BK'`, where `_` is the `LIKE` one-char wildcard, performance will be awful as it can't use any index past the prefixt `PS`. So normalizing the data is much better.

Comment: @JoeVanDyk: Don't write rules. Never use rules in Postgres. Rules are evil. Write triggers.

Comment: By rules, I meant "logic", not postgresql rules. :)